# Hasbrouck's information share

Tags: time-series, finance

Given a cointegrated set of price series, I am trying to compute the Hasbrouck's information share, as described in

page 12-13 of [this article](http://www.jamesgoulding.com/Research_II/S&P%27s/S&P%20%28Price%20Dynamics%20in%20E-minis%20revised.pdf).

page 7-8 of [this article](http://www.isb.edu/EMFConference/File/Pricediscovery%281%29.pdf)

I have the vector error correction model (VECM) set up for the price series. But I am unable to understand how to derive the vector moving average from the VECM. Does anyone have an understanding on this, on how to compute the coefficients of VMA?

Comment: You can find an R-implementation of the Hasbrouck information at: http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/tmp/infoshare.R

Comment: I'm also trying to calculate Habrouck IS.
If you still have this scrypt, could send me it somehow? I would be really thankful for this.